# How to enable firebase crashlytics while using smartlook SDK?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am using Smartlook SDK in my android app.
Website Link : https://www.smartlook.com/

The problem is i can't get crash report in crashlytics and yes app is also not getting crashed (Even by writing code that would definitely carsh like "divided by zero" ) after integrating Smartlook SDK in my project.